# PHP regex error. Compilation failed

Tags: php, regex

```
if (preg_match('/*\-*\-*/', $controlNum))
```

And I receive this warning message:

> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 0

What could be wrong?

Comment: Apart from `*` is a reserved char that has to be escaped: What do you want to check here?

Comment: BTW: It's not necessary to escape the hyphens here (it a reserved char in squared brackets only).

Comment: You did escaping those chars which wouldn't be escaped

Comment: The first * is causing the error, because as it, it is a quantifier and should follow a quantifiable token.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must escape `*`

```
if (preg_match('/\*\-\*\-\*/', $controlNum))
```

The asterisk is a quantifier meaning *one or more occurrences of the preceding pattern*. The error is caused by the first `*` that is in the beginning of the pattern.

*Update*:

As it has been pointed out in the comments, you do not need to escape hyphens when outside of character class. You might as well write

```
if (preg_match('/\*-\*-*/', $controlNum))
```

Or also use a limiting quantifier with a non-capturing group:

```
if (preg_match('/\*(?:-\*){2}/', $controlNum))
```

These should match `*-*-*`.